# Create shopping cart price rule with coupon on clicking Place Order

Tags: orders, shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon, coupon-codes

I am working on a custom module in which I need to generate a coupon with "n" number of uses per order while clicking "Place Order" in checkout page.

Can anyone suggest me the best way for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly is your problem? you hook into the `sales_order_place_after`(?) event and generate coupon codes for a given rule. If you need to define the rule, you create the rule beforehand and afterwards the coupons.

Comment: Thank You.. can you pls share me the script to generate coupon that's hassle free for place order event.. if u have any!